# GAE - cannot deploy gwt app which uses UserService

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, deployment, gae-eclipse-plugin, gae-userservice

I tried to deploy my app using [auth this instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml?csw=1#Security_and_Authentication) as :

```
<application>mytestapp</application>
          <version>1</version>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

        <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and I tried [this code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers?csw=1) as well to make user login:

```
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
              throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
        }
    }
}
```

... but for some reason I get exception thrown as ***XML error validating*** :

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying testapp to Google". XML
>   error validating C:...\testapp\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml against
>   C:...\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.2.r37v201107211953\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.2\docs\appengine-web.xsd

I am not pretty sure what that means so I dearly need your advise how to fix it? Any useful idea is much appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. GWT SDK 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the [app config file: `appengine-web.xml`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) with [deployment descriptor: `web.xml`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml).